# Let $f:(-a,a)\setminus\{0\} \to (0,+\infty)$.If $\lim(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)})=2$ ,then $\lim(f(x))=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Now the simple problem with these types of sums is that I am not getting any intuition and since I am not getting any intuition I am not able to try.Can anyone please give me some hints , and the geometric picture behind this?

Comment: Limit at which point? Is it $0$??

Comment: **Hint** set $\lim_{x\to ?}f(x)=\ell$. Then $\ell+\frac{1}{\ell}=2$.